# php htaccess seo multi language

Tags: php, .htaccess

I normally keep a record in session for the language, but what I want is, instead of keeping it in session **mysite.com/tr** **mysite.com/en** **mysite.com/ar**
I want to do it but when I enter **mysite.com/tr** I get stuck in 404 error in the app.

**mysite.com/tr/blog**

**mysite.com/en/blog**

**mysite.com/ar/blog**

```
<div class="topbar-dropdown">
<div class="title" id="language">
<a href="lang?lang=tr"><img src="images/tr.png"></a>
<a href="lang?lang=en"><img src="images/en.png"></a>
<a href="lang?lang=ar"><img src="images/ar.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

**app/controller/lang.php**

```
$lang = strip_tags($_GET['lang']);
if ($lang == "tr" || $lang == "en" || $lang == "ar") {
$_SESSION['language'] = $lang;
header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}else {
header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?category=$1&service=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)$ index.php [QSA]
```

**app.php**

```
function controller($controllerName)
{
    $controllerName = strtolower($controllerName);
    return PATH . '/app/controller/' . $controllerName . '.php';
}

function view($viewName)
{
    return PATH . '/app/view/'. $viewName . '.php';
}

function route($index)
{
    global $route;
    return isset($route[$index]) ? $route[$index] : false;
}
if (!file_exists(controller(route(0)))) {
    $route[0] = '404';
}
```

**index.php**

```
$routeExplode = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$route = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', $routeExplode[0])));
if (SUBFOLDER_NAME != '/') {
    array_shift($route);
}

if (!route(0)) {
    $route[0] = 'index';
}
```

**config.php**

```
define('PATH', realpath('.'));
define('SUBFOLDER_NAME', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
define('URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . (SUBFOLDER_NAME == '/' ? null : SUBFOLDER_NAME));
```

Comment: And, what have you done to try and debug this so far - and with what results?

Comment: You need to go read up on how unreliable the HTTP Referer is. `header('Location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` will likely fail for a lot of users, that have privacy enhancing extensions or other stuff installed, that could filter this out, or shorten/manipulate it. The referrer is something you _never_ want to use for something important like this.

Comment: My teacher, I did not do anything because I do not have much knowledge of php and htaccess. in app.php $route[0] = '404'; Activated